# SQL - Using INSERT INTO with SELECT DISTINCT resulting in NULL values being imported

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have what should be a relatively simple problem that I need a solution to. I am beginner to SQL and would greatly appreciate any assistance.

I have been trying to import all the unique Strings from one column (bond) in my 'customer' table, to a new column that I've created in my 'bonds' table.

I have been using the following code:

```
INSERT INTO bonds(bond_customer_name) SELECT DISTINCT bond FROM customer;
```

While the SELECT DISTINCT on its own selects the correct 25 records, 1500+ are being imported when I run the above query, with a large proportion of the fields being NULL.

The new bond_customer_name column also has the same data type as the original bond column (VARCHAR(16)).

Comment: Does it insert 25 rows with NULL as bond_customer_name, or only one?

Comment: It is inserting 25 NULL rows.

Comment: Your syntax seems correct in MS SQL : "INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;"

Comment: Do you get any warning when you run the query using mysql client ("show warnings" after the query will give you the list)?

Comment: Nope, no errors or warnings.

Comment: Can you give create table statements for both tables?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, turns out I was making a silly mistake in the end; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was creating a list of NULL values upon adding a column for bond_customer_name. Instead, I created a column, name, upon creation of the table, using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE 'bonds' ('id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'name' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY('id')) DEFAULT CHARSET = UTF8;
```

I then used the following code to successfully import the unique Strings present in Customer.bond into Bonds.name, adding a conditional WHERE:

```
INSERT INTO bonds(name) SELECT DISTINCT bond FROM customer WHERE bond IS NOT NULL;
```

This has given me the desired result, thanks to all who helped!